# Almacenar Informacion en un modal Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy tratando de realizar una consulta donde se muestra el id una imagen y estoy intentando meter un modal que al salir, muestre informacion referente al id, en una tabla sale bien la informacion, pero al meter el modal, la informacion se repite y no corresponde al id.
si pudieran ayudarme se los agradeceria muchisimo!, anexo el codigo y las imagenes de mi resultado.[image: img1]
En esta parte se muestra la consulta, en el boton Fade in Modal se debe desplegar la descripcion de cada Id, si el id es dos debera decir gatito, si el Id es 6, debera decir another y asi sucesivamente

[image: img2]Al presionar el boton se deberia desplegar la descripcion referente al id2, pero me muestra la de el numero 7, y asi me sucede con todos los botones

Codigo de mi tabla

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
   
   <!--COMIENZA CATALOGO   -->

    <center> <h2>Publicidad</h2></center>
    <div class="container">            <table id="a1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($a1 as $a2)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$a2->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$a2->descripcion}}</td>
    <td> <img style="width:85px; height:85px;" src="{{ asset('imag/'.$a2->imagen) }}"></td>
    <td>    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Fade In Modal</button>
    </a>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
          <header class="w3-container w3-teal">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
            class="w3-button w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </header>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <p>{{$a2->descripcion}}</p>
          </div>
          <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
            <p>Modal Footer</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--TERMINA EL CATALOGO-->
```

Como veran estoy trayendo la informacion con un foreach, no se si deba usar jquery, sinceramente no se mucho acerca de ello por eso no lo intente asi.

Comment: En la sección del código que publicaste, veo se repite el código desde el comentario `<!--COMIENZA CATALOGO   -->` hasta `<!--TERMINA EL CATALOGO-->` eso esta bien o fue un error de copiar y pegar?

Comment: Como el modal está después del foreach, `{{$a2->descripcion}}` siempre va a tener el valor del último elemento del foreach. O haces un modal para cada elemento del foreach (no recomendado). O usas javascript para pasarle al modal los datos que quieres mostrar.

Comment: es error de copiar y pegar , pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como la pregunta solo tiene etiqueta "laravel", lo que puedes hacer es crear un modal para cada fila de la tabla. Tendrás que ponerle una id única a cada uno, para lo que puedes usar la variable [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable)

```
@foreach ($a1 as $a2)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$a2->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$a2->descripcion}}</td>
    <td> <img style="width:85px; height:85px;" src="{{ asset('imag/'.$a2->imagen) }}"></td>
    <td><button onclick="document.getElementById('id0{{$loop->iteration}}').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Fade In Modal</button></td>

    <div id="id0{{$loop->iteration}}'" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
          <header class="w3-container w3-teal">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id0{{$loop->iteration}}').style.display='none'"
            class="w3-button w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </header>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <p>{{$a2->descripcion}}</p>
          </div>
          <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
            <p>Modal Footer</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me funciono. habia estado usando anteriormente un carrousel con la funcion de loop similar, pero no se usarla aun ya que es nueva para mi

Comment: Sí, es una opción para que la id de la etiqueta sea única, puede haber otras maneras también, pero esa está fácil